# How can I get TabBarIOS to pop to the top of the navigation stack using react-native?

Tags: react-native, tabbar, tabbarios

I have the following TabBarIOS.Item setup:

```
          <TabBarIOS.Item
            selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'tab1'}
            title='Tab 1'
            icon={require('./Components/Icons/IconImages/Tab1Icon.png')}
            onPress={() => {
              this.setState({
                selectedTab: 'tab1'
              });

             }}>
            <MyNavigatorIOS client={this.state.client} initialStep={this.state.initialStep} />

          </TabBarIOS.Item>
```

I am trying to use the `onPress` event to fire `this.props.navigator.popToTop();` as per [this example in the react native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.24/docs/navigatorios.html). The difference, however, is that I want the TabBarIOS `onPress` event to fire `popToTop()` and not the child `MyNavigatorIOS` component. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, what you can do is add a ref to your view and to the navigator inside of it, like so:

```
          this.refs.timeline.refs.timelineNavigator.popToTop()
```

So the TabBar code looks like this:

```
    <TabBarIOS.Item
      systemIcon="history"
      title="Timeline"
      badge={this.state.timelineBadge}
      selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'timeline'}
      onPress={() => {
        if (this.state.selectedTab === 'timeline') {
          this.refs.timeline.refs.timelineNavigator.popToTop()
        } else {
          this.setState({ selectedTab: 'timeline' })
        }
      }}>
      <Timeline
        ref="timeline"
      /> 
    </TabBarIOS.Item>
```

Comment: That looks like it would work! I ended up solving it by using `EventEmitter` and handling the event in the appropriate child screens. This looks nicer though =)